# Why do we say like "as noun as"?

Tags: adverbs

> I am seven times **as** old as your were when I was old as you are.
>
> I was **as** good as you are.
>
> I will go **as** well as him.
>
> I was eight times **as** good as you are.
>
> go as fast as you can.

Except for the 3rd, I wonder why the **as** is required in these kinds of sentence or sentences. Why can't I say, **I was good as you are.** How is the **as** acting actually?

Reconstructions:In the first, the **as** can be replaced by **in** and in the third, **I was good like you are.**

Comment: Ignoring the fact that it should be ***you*** not ***your*** in the first example, I have to say that's an incredibly confusing was of saying *I am seven times as old as you [**are**]*.

Comment: Note that because *I was good as you are* is "non-idiomatic", it risks being [mis]interpreted as *You are good. I am **also** good.*

Comment: We are comparing degrees of goodness. I have same amount of goodness as you have. **amount of goodness** == **as good**

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, it's a bit more complicated than that. `Let A := “me”, B := “you”. A_is = 7 * B_was; B_was = B_is – (A_is – [A_was = B_is]) => A_is = 7/4 * B_is.` Note that it says “.. when I was [as] old as you **are** [**now**].”

Comment: @AnubhavSingh Where is the construction "as [noun] as" in these sentences? I see only "as [adj] as" and "as [adv] as." In the first sentence you propose this: **I am seven times _in_ old...** A preposition cannot take an adjective as its object. This construction is quite simple. See [**this link.**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/as-as)

Comment: @user2684291: You're quite right (which just goes to prove my point - it's *very* confusing! :) Actually, it's probably more because I'm not very good at handling this sort of stuff in *words* - plus the basic format makes me think we're supposed to be able to answer the question *How old am I?* But we can't, because I could be *any* age so long as it's 7/4's of *your* age.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do I grievously missaprehend something? The OP's questions asks about _“as noun as”,_ and I can't find it here.

Comment: @P. E. Dant: Search me. For all I know, OP only posted this to mess with our heads in that first example (it obviously worked on *me!* :) Seriously, since the OP isn't a native speaker, we can prolly assume he means *word*, not *noun*. But I'm not sure enough about that to edit the text. Anyway, there's an answer with something that interests *me*, and if it doesn't enlighten OP he can always ask for clarification. Now Colin has "taken ownership" of the question, I doubt there could be anything OP might want to know that *he* couldn't answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well said. Welsh equatives!

Comment: When something is "for the good", what is good if not an abstract noun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using “as anything as” compares the value of two things, rather than separately giving either of them an independent value.

The price of a virtuous woman might be ‘as rubies’, ‘that of rubies’, or ‘as that of rubies’ but none of those puts her price ‘far above rubies.’

All three give ‘the value of rubies’ to Mrs Virtue; they make her ‘as valuable as rubies’. Mrs Virtue might ‘make a present’ *for* her beloved Solomon; she could not ‘make a present *to*’ anyone. Strictly, she might ‘give a present to’ or ‘make a presentation.’ To ‘make a presentation to’ would involve using a slide projector, not giving a prize.

To chop out each 1st ‘as’ would kill all the other examples and leave ‘I will go well as him’ lying injured.

Whether it’s actually clever or funny, ‘I am seven times as old…’ is an algebraic conundrum, not a linguistic distortion. It’s purpose is to be confusing and it’s meaning is not ‘I am seven times as old as you.’

‘I was as good as you are’ indicates that in the past I was as good as you now are. ‘The past’ could be 50 years or 10 minutes.

‘I was good as you are’ says nothing about how good I am now. It might well be interpreted as ‘I was once good and you are now good’ with no measure except that neither was bad. The function of the second ‘as’ would be to indicate one being better or both being the same.

‘I will go as well as him’ indicates two people traveling together with no question of their going having value, because of the nature of the verb. With the same construction ‘I will race as well as him’ would not distinguish between running at the same time, whoever won, and running equally fast, perhaps in different time trials.

‘I will go well as him’ indicates perhaps an actor preparing to play a part.

‘I was eight times as good as you are’ is no different in form from ‘I was as good as you are’ even though it contains a specific value.

‘Go as fast as you can’ indicates a comparison of intended speed against possible speed.

‘Go fast as you can’ indicates the speaker is a learner attempting to understand the language.

‘Go fast’ is a simple imperative.

Comment: By the way, the reason I've wiped my brains out trying to solve "I am seven times as old as your were when I was old as you are…" is that as stated, it can't be solved. The sum of their ages was left out. B gger!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is "Because that is how English does it".

Different languages have their own patterns. English uses "as X as Y" - in the negative we can alternatively use "so": "not as X as Y" or "not so X as Y", but this is not common in positive sentences.

For an example of how another language does it: literary Welsh has a special form of the adjective known as the "equative" that is used in this kind of construction, in addition to the comparative and superlative found in English and many other languages. So *hen* = 'old', *henach* = 'older', but *mor hened â* = 'as old as'

Comment: That's an interesting point about ***so*** not being common in positive sentences. I was minded to think *particularly not in more recent times,* so I did [an NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+so+bad+as%2Cnot+as+bad+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20so%20bad%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20as%20bad%20as%3B%2Cc0) for ***not so/as bad as***. Apparently usage has massively changed in the last century, but I don't think it was ever normal to say *I speak French **so** well as I speak English* (or ***so badly*** either).

Answer (score 0):

Let's chop out each 1st **as** and see what happens:

```
I am seven times old as you were when I was old as you are.
```

Probably equivalent, but so much more confusing -- a *comma* after *were* might help.  The 2nd "old" lacks a preceding "as", and could be replaced with "young".  ("I am seven times old as you were, when I was young as you are.")  That works, but having *four* instances of **as** is more musical, which makes for a more memorable riddle.

```
I was good as you are.
```

Implies the speaker may no longer be good.

```
I will go well as him.
```

The speaker contemplates identity theft.

```
I was eight times good as you are.
```

Implies the speaker is even better now.

```
go fast as you can.
```

More imperative.